# Android getting data from Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I'm having trouble trying to get the data from my Listview, then setting that String of data in a EditText once the user selects a product from the list. What do I need to do this code to make this happen? Thanks in advance.

(Also, sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm new to android and Java)

Activity with EditText:

```
EditText CPU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView4);
    CPU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent CPUList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    CPUList.class);
            startActivityForResult(CPUList, RESULT_OK);
        }

    });
```

List activity

```
final ListView listViewCPU = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCPU);
    listViewCPU.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    String CPUList[] = {

    "CPU's go here", "CPU's go here", "CPU's go here", "CPU's go here" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CPUList);

    listViewCPU.setAdapter(adapter);

     listViewCPU.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int  pos, long mylng) {
            String CPU =(listViewCPU.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());

        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: did you try logging string CPU. do you get the right value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) contains your data. If you grab a reference to your adapter, you can fetch the string from that position.

The other thing to note is that in your OnItemClick listener you named your AdapterView myAdapter, the truth is that the adapter view is just a view that implements an adapter, so in this case the adapter view would be your listview.

Below is how you would get your string from the click listener:

```
listViewCPU.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View myView, int  pos, long mylng) {
        String CPU = (String) listview.getAdapter().getItem(pos);

    }
});
```

Comment: Where would I position the reference to my adapter?

Comment: You could make it a global variable when you initialized it earlier, or you could get it via the AdapterView argument like I have done above.

Comment: When using the code you gave me above, I get an error on "position" saying that "position is not declared to a variable"

Comment: I am now getting the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String" on "listview.getAdapter().getItem(pos);", I've also added the semi colon you missed at the end of the brackets as well, thanks for the help, hopefully we can get this fixed.

Comment: Ok, updated again by adding the semi colon and casting object to a string.

In future you would have adapter defined globally, so getItem would return a string and you wouldn't need to cast it.

Comment: Ok thank you, now it's working without errors. Just need to retrieve that string to the EditText now once an item is clicked, thanks :)